# ¿Por qué me guarda únicamente el último elemento del la lista?

Tags: python

Con este código, se me genera un csv con la fecha y el tweet correspondiente pero únicamente del último elemento de la lista, es decir del '#ElPeorGobiernoDeLaHistoria'.

```py
import GetOldTweets3 as got
import pandas as pd
import datetime

keywords = ['saqueo chile','vandalismo chile','delincuencia chile','ataque carabinero','ataque comisaria','ataque subcomisaria',' manifestacion chile','protesta chile','bomba molotov','coctel molotov','funa chile','incendio intencional','quema transantiago','matapaco','#matapaco','#chiledesperto','#piñeraculiao','#renunciapiñera','plaza de la dignidad' ,'#chaopiñera','#primeralinea','incendio iglesia','#piensaprensa','#chileoculto','#plazadeladignidad','#ElPeorGobiernoDeLaHistoria' ]
user = 'piensaprensa'


for keyword in keywords:
    def text_query_to_csv(keyword, count):

        # Creation of query object
        tweetCriteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setQuerySearch(keyword).setSince(since_date).setUntil(until_date).setMaxTweets(count)
        # Creation of list that contains all tweets
        tweets = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)
        # Creating list of chosen tweet data
        text_tweets = [[tweet.date, tweet.text] for tweet in tweets]


        # Creation of dataframe from tweets
        tweets_df = pd.DataFrame(text_tweets, columns = ['Datetime','Text'])

        # Converting tweets dataframe to csv file
        tweets_df.to_csv('{}-{}-tweets.csv'.format(keyword, count), sep=',')



#since_date = '2020-01-/22'
# until_date = str(datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
#desde hoy
since_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  
#hasta mañana para que tome el dia de hoy solamente
until_date = (datetime.today()+ timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 
count = 20
text_query_to_csv(keyword, count)
```

También me gustaría lograr que se guarden todos los tweets en un mismo csv. 
¿Cómo podria hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "me genera un csv con la fecha y el tweet correspondiente pero únicamente del último elemento de la lista"

El problema es que llamas a la función una sola vez en la última línea:

```
text_query_to_csv(keyword, count)
```

cuando deberías llamarla una vez por cada palabra de la lista, es decir llamarla en cada iteración del ciclo `for`. En cambio, en el ciclo `for` te limitas a redefinir la función inútilmente. Cuando la llamas al final del código la variable `keyword` contiene el último item de la lista (valor asignado en la última iteración del `for`) y es con este parámetro con el que llamas a la función.

Puede ser solo un error de identación, pero sea como sea la definición de la función no debe estar dentro del ciclo:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import GetOldTweets3 as got
import pandas as pd


keywords = ['saqueo chile', 'vandalismo chile', 'delincuencia chile',
            'ataque carabinero', 'ataque comisaria', 'ataque subcomisaria',
            ' manifestacion chile', 'protesta chile', 'bomba molotov',
            'coctel molotov', 'funa chile', 'incendio intencional',
            'quema transantiago', 'matapaco', '#matapaco', '#chiledesperto',
            '#piñeraculiao', '#renunciapiñera', 'plaza de la dignidad' ,
            '#chaopiñera', '#primeralinea' ,'incendio iglesia', '#piensaprensa',
            '#chileoculto', '#plazadeladignidad', '#ElPeorGobiernoDeLaHistoria'
            ]
user = 'piensaprensa'


def text_query_to_csv(keyword, count):

    # Creation of query object
    tweetCriteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setQuerySearch(keyword).setSince(since_date).setUntil(until_date).setMaxTweets(count)
    # Creation of list that contains all tweets
    tweets = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)
    # Creating list of chosen tweet data
    text_tweets = [[tweet.date, tweet.text] for tweet in tweets]


    # Creation of dataframe from tweets
    tweets_df = pd.DataFrame(text_tweets, columns = ['Datetime','Text'])

    # Converting tweets dataframe to csv file
    tweets_df.to_csv('{}-{}-tweets.csv'.format(keyword, count), sep=',')


#desde hoy
since_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  
#hasta mañana para que tome el dia de hoy solamente
until_date = (datetime.today()+ timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 
count = 20

for keyword in keywords:
    text_query_to_csv(keyword, count)
```

En cuanto a lo de generar un único csv, basta con agrupar todo en el mismo dataframe. Puedes simplemente prescindir de la función y hacer algo como:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import GetOldTweets3 as got
import pandas as pd



keywords = ['saqueo chile', 'vandalismo chile', 'delincuencia chile',
            'ataque carabinero', 'ataque comisaria', 'ataque subcomisaria',
            ' manifestacion chile', 'protesta chile', 'bomba molotov',
            'coctel molotov', 'funa chile', 'incendio intencional',
            'quema transantiago', 'matapaco', '#matapaco', '#chiledesperto',
            '#piñeraculiao', '#renunciapiñera', 'plaza de la dignidad' ,
            '#chaopiñera', '#primeralinea' ,'incendio iglesia', '#piensaprensa',
            '#chileoculto', '#plazadeladignidad', '#ElPeorGobiernoDeLaHistoria'
            ]
user = 'piensaprensa'

#desde hoy
since_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  
#hasta mañana para que tome el dia de hoy solamente
until_date = (datetime.today()+ timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 
count = 20

text_tweets = []
for keyword in keywords:
    # Creation of query object
    tweetCriteria = (got.manager.TweetCriteria()
                                .setQuerySearch(keyword)
                                .setSince(since_date).setUntil(until_date)
                                .setMaxTweets(count)
                                )
    tweets = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)
    text_tweets += [[tweet.date, tweet.text, keyword] for tweet in tweets]

tweets_df = pd.DataFrame(text_tweets, columns=['Datetime', 'Text', 'keyword'])
tweets_df.to_csv('tweets.csv', sep=',')
```

He añadido una nueva columna para identificar la `keyword` de cada tweet, no se si lo necesitas o no.

Realmente crear un DataFrame para esto solo es ineficiente, sería mejor usar directamente el módulo csv de la biblioteca estándar y trabajar con generadores.

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucione el tema de la lista. Estaba  indentando mal. Corri una tabulacion a la izquierda las ultimas lineas para que queden dentro del **for** pero fuera del **def**

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
#desde hoy
since_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  
#hasta mañana para que tome el dia de hoy solamente
until_date = (datetime.today()+ timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 
count = 20
text_query_to_csv(keyword, count)
```

Me quedaria solucionar  el tema de como puedo hacer para guardar todas en un mismo csv.